# calling function with multi-variable functions

Tags: matlab, function

I have the following function which finds the zero of a function using Newton-Raphson:

```
function [ x,i ] = nr_function( x0,f,fp )

N   = 15;
eps = 1e-5;

x=x0;
for i=0:N
    if( abs(f(x))<eps )
        return;
    end

    x=x-f(x)/fp(x);
end
```

I can call the function like this:

```
f = @(x) x.^3-1
fp = @(x) 3*x.^2
nr_function(3, f,fp)
```

However, say I instead define my function like this, i.e. taking 2 variables:

```
f = @(x, q) q*x.^3-1
fp = @(x, q) q*3*x.^2
```

Then how would I be able to call `nr_function` with f and fp? I tried `nr_function(3, f,fp)`, but that doesn't work

Comment: `q` in this case is defined at the call of `nr_function`?

Comment: @Matt Yes, it is defined when I call  `nr_function`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `q` is defined when you call `nr_function`, you can use an anonymous function in the call. When you do this, then the argument you pass is a *new* function-handle with variable `x` and constant `q`.

```
f  = @(x, q) q*x.^3-1
fp = @(x, q) q*3*x.^2

q = 1;

nr_function(3, @(x)f(x,q), @(x)fp(x,q))
```

**Note:** It's not necessary that you use the variable `x` in the anonymous function. The only importance is to have a single argument in the end. So we can use for example `y` as the intermediate variable like this:

```
nr_function(3, @(y)f(y,q), @(y)fp(y,q))
```

If we expand it to multiple lines, it would look like this:

```
f  = @(x, q) q*x.^3-1
fp = @(x, q) q*3*x.^2

q = 1;

f2  = @(y) f(y,q)
fp2 = @(y) fp(y,q)

nr_function(3, f2, fp2)
```